# about ItemEvent in java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

I'm doing a small program with Java GUI
here is mu code:

```
    // DebugFourteen3
// User selects pizza topping and sees price
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//use correct spelling of class name
public class DebugFourteen3 extends JFrame
{ 
   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
   JComboBox pizzaBox = new JComboBox();
   JLabel toppingList = new JLabel("Topping List");
   JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Paulos's American Pie");
   JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
   int[] pizzaPrice = {7,10,10,8,8,8,8};
   int totalPrice = 0;
   String output;
   int pizzaNum;
   public DebugFourteen3()
   {
      super("Pizza List");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(flow);
      add(toppingList);
      pizzaBox.addItem("cheese");
      pizzaBox.addItem("sausage");
      pizzaBox.addItem("pepperoni");
      pizzaBox.addItem("onion");
      pizzaBox.addItem("green pepper");
      pizzaBox.addItem("green olive");
      pizzaBox.addItem("black olive");
      add(pizzaBox);
      add(aLabel);
      add(totPrice);
      itemStateChanged(this);
   }

   public static void main(String[] arguments)
   {
      JFrame frame = new DebugFourteen3();
      frame.setSize(200, 150);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)
   {
      Object source = list.getSource();
      if(source == pizzaBox)
      {
         int pizzaNum = pizzaBox.getSelectedIndex();
         totalPrice = pizzaPrice[pizzaNum];
         output = "Pizza Price $" + totalPrice;
         totPrice.setText(output);
      }
   }
}
```

the compiler gets me error on line 35, it says itemStateChanged() should receive a argument which type is ItemEvent[] but I'm passing "this"(the class it self)

can anyone explain how the itemStateChanged works with the JComboBox?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the listener on the combo box instead of calling the `itemStateChanged` method directly.  Adding the listener will enable the callbacks when the click event happens, and jvm will call the `itemStateChanged` method automatically as combo box is registered for the event. Replace this line

```
  itemStateChanged(this);
```

with

```
pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to implements `ItemListener` with `JFrame`. Than add following line with `pizzaBox`, this will notify overrided `public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev)` method `ItemListener`.

```
pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
```

For details, see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

1.you are not registering `itemListener` for `JComboBox`
2.`itemStateChanged` event takes `ItemEvent` as argument not `ItemEvent[]` array

1.Replace this :

```
itemStateChanged(this);
```

with this:

```
pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
```

2.Replace This:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)
```

With this:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list)
```

**Complete Code:**

```
// DebugFourteen3
// User selects pizza topping and sees price
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//use correct spelling of class name
public class DebugFourteen3 extends JFrame
{ 
   FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
   JComboBox pizzaBox = new JComboBox();
   JLabel toppingList = new JLabel("Topping List");
   JLabel aLabel = new JLabel("Paulos's American Pie");
   JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(10);
   int[] pizzaPrice = {7,10,10,8,8,8,8};
   int totalPrice = 0;
   String output;
   int pizzaNum;
   public DebugFourteen3()
   {
      super("Pizza List");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setLayout(flow);
      add(toppingList);
      pizzaBox.addItem("cheese");
      pizzaBox.addItem("sausage");
      pizzaBox.addItem("pepperoni");
      pizzaBox.addItem("onion");
      pizzaBox.addItem("green pepper");
      pizzaBox.addItem("green olive");
      pizzaBox.addItem("black olive");
      add(pizzaBox);
      add(aLabel);
      add(totPrice);
      pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
   }

   public static void main(String[] arguments)
   {
      JFrame frame = new DebugFourteen3();
      frame.setSize(200, 150);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent list)
   {
      Object source = list.getSource();
      if(source == pizzaBox)
      {
         int pizzaNum = pizzaBox.getSelectedIndex();
         totalPrice = pizzaPrice[pizzaNum];
         output = "Pizza Price $" + totalPrice;
         totPrice.setText(output);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` i.e `DebugFourteen3` is not a type `ItemEvent`. Thats why

```
itemStateChanged(ItemEvent[] list)
```

gives error.

If you want to handle `itemStateChanged` then you need to implement `ItemLisntener` and add `actionListner` to it as

```
pizzaBox.addItemListener(this);
```

also add Handler method of `ItemLisntener` as

```
public void itemStateChanged(....)
{
    //Handling Code  goes here
}
```

Or you can implement `ActionListner` also 
For more information on how to use combobox you can visit [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)